# Change directory using sudo

Tags: linux, ubuntu, shell

How to I change into a directory owned by root?

If I do: `sudo cd RootOwedDir`

I get: `sudo cd: command not found`

If I `su root`

I get: `authentication failure`, probably because I never really set up an actual root account.

What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: To summarize: both cYrus's "sudo su" and "sudo sh -sc "cd dir_path" (note the additions 's' parm) solved the problem.  Thanks to everyone for their help.

Answer (score 26, accepted):

Instead try using `sudo -s` to start a root shell and then simply `cd` into the directory.
When you're done as root, press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>D</kbd> or type `exit`.

It is important to note that as root, one can easily do damage to essential system components. **Use with care!**

Answer (score 6):

```
sudo sh -c "cd dir_path"
```

Comment: This is not working for me either.  It might be because the directory I want to enter has embedded spaces in the name.  I have tried variations on sudo sh -c "cd my\ path" with no luck.  No error message it just returns as if it did something but I remain in the same directory.  sh is installed on my system though I normally use bash.

Comment: @unknown - I've always figured you'd have to spawn a subshell to run shell builtins as root, whether in bash or plain old sh. I'm determined to figure this out.

Comment: Adding the -s option along -c did the trick.  Thanks for the effort.

Answer (score 5):

That's because `cd` isn't a command but a built-in shell function; and `su` expects the root password. Simply use:

```
sudo su
```

to run a shell with root privileges. Type `exit` or press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>D</kbd> to return to the previous shell when you're done.

Comment: `sudo su` is unnecessarily complicated. `sudo -s` makes sudo start a shell; or you can run `sudo bash` or `sudo zsh` if you don't want to have to remember the `-s` option.

Comment: To add to what @Gilles'SO-stopbeingevil' already said: you're using two programs (`sudo` and `su`) to do something that a single one could do. On some machines you might only have `su` available, on other you might have only `sudo`. It's better to learn to use both of these tools effectively than to memorize `sudo su`, even if it's a widely used practice.

Answer (score 1):

You can also do a `sudo vim` on the folder, ie `sudo vim RootOwedDir` and it will show the vim view for folders, which will show all the files/folders that are in that folder. then you can just run what you need to from outside the folder, and sudo it just like normal.

Answer (score 0):

`su -` then type in your password. You now can just cd into the directory. Remember tho you are now root so ctrl-d before you do anything you don't want to be root for.

Comment: That produces an authentication error on Ubuntu.

Comment: Really? I have never had an issue for me.

Comment: For OP it would, certainly, as he doesn't doesn't have a proper root account.

Comment: Interesting, I am on a fresh install of Ubuntu, I never 'setup' a root user yet I can simply `sudo -` and bam I am god of the system.

Comment: Yeah, I just get an authentication error.

Comment: `sudo -s` is the ticket here.

Comment: @MrStatic: `sudo` requires the password of the calling user. `su` requires the password of the target user. They have different command line syntaxes. They are not interchangeable.

Comment: @oKtosiTe - the -s option along -c did the trick.  If you want to add a post I can at least give you a couple of points.

Answer (score 0):

For me a combination of `sudo` and `screen` worked out:

```
sudo -iu vagrant screen -mS npm_install bash -c 'cd /vagrant && npm install'
```

This command first switches to the `vagrant` user. Then as `vagrant` changes the directory to `/vagrant` and executes `npm install`.

Answer (score -3):

The easiest way to do this is to enable the root account and use **su** to become root. Ubuntu is very protective of the root account due to the potential for misuse, but at times, it is much easier to use the root account rather than **sudo** on every line. Just be aware of what account you are using at any given time.

Taken from [here](http://www.sizlopedia.com/2008/04/16/how-to-login-to-ubuntu-as-root-user/):

> Open the terminal and type: **sudo passwd root**.
>   When you see the prompt that says *“Enter new UNIX password”*, enter the password you want for the root user and confirm it.

At this point, you will be able to change to root using **su** and **cd** to the directory.

Comment: -1. This is full of wrong. What does GDM have to do with anything? OP wants to 'cd' to a dir readable only by root. No one should ever log in as root via GDM.

Comment: Good point. I didn't fully read what I was pasting there.

Comment: Much easier than this is enabling a root shell with sudo -s as others have said, and much better than this is learning about sudo, a much more flexible and granular tool than su, if well used.